# PHP split string number and special character

Tags: php, regex

I need to split this format of strings

```
1234*34*34#1000,cn:123#10000

1317#1000,2174#10000

cb:1*2#20,3#25

ab#10,abcd#15

cjE*5#25
```

into array like below,

[0] => 1234, [1] => 34, [2] => 1000, [3] => cn, [4] => 123, [5] => 10000

is it possible to do it all

Comment: so practically all special characters are separators ?

Comment: You need to state the *rule* for dividing the strings. One possibility, for example, is that you want to match each string consisting of all digits or all lower-case letters.

Comment: @MaxMuster yes bro

Comment: all string is lower-case letters the string and number will be save to database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
$str = '1234*34*34#1000,cn:123#10000';

$a = preg_split("/[*#,:]/", $str);
var_dump($a);
```

Will output

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "1234"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "34"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "34"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "1000"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "cn"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "123"
  [6]=>
  string(5) "10000"
}
```

Comment: OP stated in a comment that it's just non-alphanumeric chars that should be split on. That'd make a much more reliable regex in case the examples were not exhaustive.

Comment: @JasonGroulx hello bro how if i want to loop this data 1234*34*34#1000,cn:123#10000 use foreach? the result is something like this 1234 34 34 1000 and next data is like cn 123 10000